# Can I alter the DNS cache on my Computer?

Tags: dns, windows-10, dns-spoofing, caching

Can I alter the DNS cache of my computer.

When I search online it only shows result to flush DNS cache and not how to alter it.
 The DNS cache saved on Windows consist of URL,serverIP and many other fields.
Can I edit this serverIP field of any cached url on my windows10 ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by adding the desired host entries in the host file.As per my exploration,DNS cache files are not available but you can override DNS cache entries by making entries in system host file.

Reference:https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-use-the-hosts-file-to-fake-dns/

Answer (score 0):

The DNS cache is stored in memory only and maintained by the "DNS Client" service (Dnscache).

I doubt there is a build-in way to alter the dns cache, so you'd need to search svchost.exe for strings representing the entry you want to change.